# What's the proper way to cleanup an infinite loop application in Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, cross-platform

I come from a primarily Windows environment, so I'm a bit lost making a transition to writing some things in Linux.

Say I've got a simple C/C++ application like so:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int h = open("something");

    while (true)
    {
        // do work
        usleep(10000);
    }

    close(h);
}
```

In Windows, I'd use something like `GetAsyncKeyState()` (or some other sort of keyboard checking functionality) to look for say the escape key, and break out of my loop when it was pressed. That way my `close(h)` would get called, and I'd do all the cleanup I need to.

The way I've been terminating my applications in Linux has been using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, which from my reading means it sends `SIGINT`, and is a 'friendly' way to cause an application to quit. However, in my experience, that's just caused it to sorta drop everything and close wherever it was when it got that signal (meaning my post-loop cleanup never runs.)

Some have suggested I use `signal()` to listen for `SIGINT`, but others disagree with that method. (Plus, it tends to create a bit more differences between how things are done between Windows and Linux, and I'd like to stay as close as possible to running on both platforms.)

Is there a 'best practice' for things like this?

Comment: when a process exists all handles are closed automatically. if that's your only cleanup reason, it's perfectly valid to rely on ctrl-c.

Comment: Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ and the `intro(2)` man page. Also read about multiplexing syscalls like `poll(2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `SIGINT` handler is actually the normal way to handle these things in the POSIX world, and similar to using [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows.

In the `SIGINT` signal handler, you set a flag, and the loop checks this flag if it should exit or not.

However, it's not strictly needed, unless you have special needs in your cleanup (like for example sending a goodbye-message to other applications or similar). The OS will make sure all files are closed properly, all memory allocations are free'd, etc. Just the same as in Windows.

Answer (score 3):

The default action of SIGINT is to terminate the program in a normal way. All open files are automatically closed when the program exits in this way, so it doesn't matter that `close` isn't explicitly run.

It's certainly possible to set up a signal handler to close the program, but for something like this it would be overkill. Generally if you're pressing ctrl-c to exit a program, you are expecting a very rapid termination.

If you've got several files open which have been written to, and they all need to be in a consistent state relative to each other, you may want to handle the signal.

Comment: I liked the explanation in your answer too, but I can only mark one as the answer, and Joachim just slightly beat you to the punch. Thanks a lot, teppic!

Comment: @nitz - don't worry about it!

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you do a getch(); your program's input is blocked until a key is hit. This is called 'Canonical' processing in the unix world (canons=rules). You can turn it off. Thus when you do a getch(); and no key has been pressed, it will immediately return -1 or whatever kind of error code.

It's been 15 years for me so I'm not sure of the specifics, but, if you google ioctl, termio, canonical, noncanonical, you'll get answers right away.

But hopefully somebody will be kind enough to post a few lines of code for you! Sorry I only have a minute to answer.